# Implementing https in docassemble with let's Encrypt: Issue

Tags: docker, ubuntu, server, lets-encrypt, docassemble

Good evening everyone!
I am explaining my situation hoping that some good soul can help me :)
I use linux operating system, ubuntu. I downloaded docker to run a software called docassemble on a server.
I followed the documentation for installing docker and docassemble via docker, I needed persistent volume so I implemented them : dacerts and dabackup.
I then use this command to start the docker container:

```
sudo docker run --env-file=env.list \`
-v dabackup:/usr/share/docassemble/backup \`
-v dacerts:/usr/share/docassemble/certs \`
-d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --stop-timeout 600 \`
jhpyle/docassemble`
```

as you can see, the container takes configuration data from the env.list file:

```
DBNAME=docassemble`
DBUSER=docassemble`
DBPASSWORD=abc123`
DBHOST=localhost`
USEHTTPS=true`
DAHOSTNAME=docassemble.dominioweb.link`
USELETSENCRYPT=true`
LETSENCRYPTEMAIL=docassemble24@gmail.com`
S3ENABLE=false`
S3ACCESSKEY=`
S3SECRETACCESSKEY=`
S3BUCKET=`
S3REGION=`
EC2=false`
TIMEZONE=America/New_York`
```

I am now trying to run docassemble on the server via the https protocol and not http but when I access the page it gives me this kind of error:
your connection is not private
`NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

Would any of you know how to avoid this error?
Please feel free to ask for any further information.

Andrea

I tried to start the container without the persistent volumes and it worked, the page appeared with https protocol.

Comment: It looks like you figured it out, since the site is now up with HTTPS and Let's Encrypt. Note that the `dacerts` volume is used when you are not using Let's Encrypt and you want to supply certificates of your own for the server. Let's Encrypt will only issue duplicate certificates five times per week, so you can run into trouble if you use the same domain and run `docker run` multiple times without the `dabackup` volume that persists the Let's Encrypt renewal data.